# Facebook Logout too slow?

Tags: facebook, cookies, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

When the user clicks Logout, I trigger FB.logout() and redirect the user to the homepage.

However the homepage still thinks the user is logged in to facebook, so it redirects again to somewhere else. After the second redirect it realizes the user is logged out, but it's too late.

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="FB.logout();">Logout</a>
```

index.php:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  window.location.href='login_facebook.php?action=login';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`FB.logout`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) is supposed to be used with a callback function. If you tried

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="FB.logout(function(response){});">Logout</a>
```

you should find that the user is not redirected to index.php before `FB.logout` returns.

Comment: one issue is that not everyone is logged in by facebook. I think with this method, "regular" users will never be redirected?

Comment: While I am not sure how I could have known that you were using two different authentication systems based on your question description, I have completely changed my solution. Please try my updated answer.